# JavaScript Google Cloud Function: write Stripe values to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm new to JavaScript and I have written the following JS Google Cloud Function with the help of various resources.

This function handles a Stripe `invoice.payment_succeeded` event and instead of writing the entire `data` I am trying to save just both the sent `period_start` and `period_end` values back to the correct location in my Firebase DB (see structure below).

How can I write these two values in the same function call?

```
exports.reocurringPaymentWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const hook  = req.body.type;
  const data  = req.body.data.object;
  const status = req.body.data.object.status;
  const customer = req.body.data.object.customer;
  const period_start = req.body.data.object.period_start;
  const period_end = req.body.data.object.period_end;

  console.log('customer', customer);
  console.log('hook:', hook);
  console.log('status', status);
  console.log('data:', data);
  console.log('period_start:', period_start);
  console.log('period_end:', period_end);


return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_ids/${customer}`).once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val()).then((userId) => {
  const ref = admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${userId}/subscription/response`)
    return ref.set(data);
})
.then(() => res.status(200).send(`(200 OK) - successfully handled ${hook}`))
.catch((error) => {
  // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
  // still logging an exception with StackDriver
  return snap.ref.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
})
.then((error) => {
  return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
});

});//End
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to save the `period_start` and `period_end` values, **instead of the entire `data` object**, you can use the `update()` method (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

You should then modify your code as follows. (*Just note that it is not clear from where you receive the `userId` value, since you don't show the `stripe_ids` database node in your question. I make the assumption that it is the value at `/stripe_ids/${customer}`. You may adapt that.*)

```
exports.reocurringPaymentWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const hook  = req.body.type;
  const data  = req.body.data.object;
  const status = req.body.data.object.status;
  const customer = req.body.data.object.customer;
  const period_start = req.body.data.object.period_start;
  const period_end = req.body.data.object.period_end;


  admin.database().ref(`/stripe_ids/${customer}`).once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
     const userId = snapshot.val();
     let updates = {};
     updates[`/stripe_customers/${userId}/subscription/response/period_start`] = period_start;
     updates[`/stripe_customers/${userId}/subscription/response/period_end`] = period_end;

     return admin.database().ref().update(updates);
  })
  .then(() => res.status(200).send(`(200 OK) - successfully handled ${hook}`))
  .catch((error) => {...});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP type functions are terminated immediately after the response is sent.  In your code, you're sending the response, then attempting to do more work after that.  You will have to do all the work before the response is sent, otherwise it may get cut off.